# Android sqlite resultado undefined

Tags: android, sqlite, undefined

En una app de android (android studio) estoy guardando fotos convertidas a string base64 en una base de datos sqlite. Se guardan correctamente. Si extraigo la base de datos y la consulto con un editor de base de datos está guardada correctamente.

Pero cuando hago un select el resultado me devuelve es undefined.

```
 c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Photo FROM photo"
                , null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                c.getString(0);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

si evaluo ese c.getString me devuelve undefined. Pero si hago

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (Photo) FROM photo"
            , null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            c.getInt(0);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

este getInt me devuelve 1

¿Como puedo recuperar el texto?

Comment: Verificaste que el valor de la columna `Photo` no es `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

No se como estas creando tu bd de sqlite pero puedes probar así:

```
IMAGEN + " BLOB " //en la creación de la tabla
```

Luego lo recuperas así:

```
public Account getCurrentAccount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db       =   dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql              =   "SELECT * FROM IMAGEN";
    Cursor cursor           =   db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        this.accId             = cursor.getInt(0);
        this.accNombre           = cursor.getString(1);
        this.accImagen          = cursor.getBlob(2);
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        return null;
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Y para cargarla, así:

```
imgGuar.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( currentAccount.accImagen, 
        0,currentAccount.accImagen.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas almacenando una foto, para obtener esta imagen debes usar  `cursor.getBlob(0);` en lugar de  `cursor.getString(0);`, realiza el cambio en tu código:

```
 c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Photo FROM photo"
                , null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                //c.getString(0);
                  c.getBlob(0);  //*Obtiene imagen.
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

Comment: Hola, lo probaré pero la estoy guardando como string, no como byte[]. La combierto a base64.